# Please Help me with this complicated convergent test!

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

The question is: test $$\sum_k ((e^{k^{1/4}}+11)^{0.5}-(e^{k^{1/4}}-11)^{0.5})^k$$ for convergence. I believe I have to use the root test to get rid of the exponent of $0.5$, but after that I am absolutely lost!

Comment: I assume you rather want to test $\sum_{k=0}^\infty(\ldots)$ for convergence?

Comment: correct, sorry I forget to write the summation.

Comment: ... and the second exponent is probably not right

Comment: I apologise, I am new to the site that's why im struggling to type in the questions correctly. I have corrected it now. As you can see the entire expressions is raised to the power of K. Therefor I applied the root test and I am left with e^{k^{1/4}}+11)^{0.5}-(e^{k^{1/4}}-11)^{0.5}. Now I only need to prove that as k tends to infinite this value is less than 1. That is what I am struggling to achieve. If I simply plug in infinite for k i get infinite-infinite and I don't see a way to use l'hopital for this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are looking at the series  $$\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}\left(e^{k^{1/4}}+11\right)^{0.5}-\left(e^{k^{1/4}}-11\right)^{0.5}$$ where $N>(\log11)^{4}$  so that we are not taking the square root of a negative number.  The hint that follows will also work in the case that you are only trying to prove that the terms go to zero.

**Hint:**  Noticing that
$$\left(e^{k^{1/4}}+11\right)^{0.5}-\left(e^{k^{1/4}}-11\right)^{0.5}=\frac{22}{\sqrt{e^{k^{1/4}}+11}+\sqrt{e^{k^{1/4}}-11}},$$ we may bound the summands above by  $$\frac{22}{\sqrt{e^{k^{1/4}}+11}}\leq\frac{22}{\sqrt{e^{k^{1/4}}}}\leq22e^{-k^{1/4}}.$$   The series $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}22e^{-k^{1/4}}$  converges by comparison to other well known series (I am leaving this part for you), and so we have proven that the original series converges.

Comment: I apologise, I am new to the site that's why im struggling to type in the questions correctly. I have corrected it now. As you can see the entire expressions is raised to the power of K. Therefor I applied the root test and I am left with e^{k^{1/4}}+11)^{0.5}-(e^{k^{1/4}}-11)^{0.5}. Now I only need to prove that as k tends to infinite this value is less than 1. That is what I am struggling to achieve. If I simply plug in infinite for k i get infinite-infinite and I don't see a way to use l'hopital for this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @OmidMoj: The first equation in my hint tells you exactly what you need.  Take advantage of the fact that $$\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}.$$  In fact, my answer proves the stronger fact that the series converges, from which we deduce that the terms converge to zero.  (The contrapositive of the divergence test)

Comment: Great! one quick question, after using your hint and transforming this expression into one fraction can I simply state that since the denominator tends to infinite the entire term tend to zero which is less than 1 therefore according to the root test the original expression converges?

Comment: @OmidMoj: That sounds correct to me.